# Order of orthogonal groups over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-fields

The wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_finite_fields) gives a formula for calculating the order of an orthogonal group over finite filed $O(n,q)$:
[image]

I don't see how I can get such formula. Can one come up with some references?

Comment: Possible references for the finite classical groups are D. Taylor "The Geoemetry of the Classical Groups" and R. Wilson "The Finite Classical Groups", but it's not a topic you can expect to understand in 5 minutes. The number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=a$ in a finite field is the same for all nonzero $a$, so the answer is $(q^2-k)/(q-1)$, where $k$ is the number for $a=0$, which is $2q-1$ or $1$, depending on whether $-1$ is a square.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've moved part of the questions to a new post (which is the part I don't understand from your argument-- how can I get $(q^2-k)/(q-1)$?)

Comment: What is the order of the orthogonal group on $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old post. But this question came up on something I am doing, so I am wondering whether it is possible to answer.