# Number of solutions to $x^2+y^2=1$ in a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

This question is related to a simple case of a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564670/9464):

> How many solutions are there for
>   $$
> x^2+y^2=1
> $$
>   in a finite field $F_q$?

The answer of the this question would give the order of the orthogonal group $O_2({F_q})$.

But I don't see a way how I can count the solutions.

---

[Partial work.]
Things might boil down to count
$$
t=\left\{\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\mid u,v\in F_q,\ \ u^2+v^2\not=0\right\}
$$
which is what I learned from a post [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071120071636AAJCoaC). Let $k$ be the number of solutions to $u^2+v^2=0$. Then $q^2-k$ gives the number of possible denominators.

Comment: There is an elementary proof here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071120071636AAJCoaC which I think works for all finite fields, not just for those of prime order.

Comment: If $-1$ has a square root, then you can factor $x^2+y^2=(x+yi)(x-yi)$, and use the fact that $(x,y)\mapsto(x+iy,x-iy)$ is a non-singular linear mapping. If $-1$ is not a square, then the usual rational parametrization of the unit circle $x=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$, $y=2t/(1+t^2)$ works (save for the point $(-1,0)$ corresponding to infinite $t$). Barring a mistake I got $q-1$ and $q+1$ points in the respective cases. I'm fairly sure this has been done earlier here. Searching...

Comment: But I'm a bit worried about your relation of the number of solutions of this equation to the order of the orthogonal group. In characteristic $p$ the fun orthogonal groups are those preserving a different quadratic form from the usual one. Or rather, the classification of QFs is different. IIRC $O_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$ consists of matrices $A$ such that $A^TJA=J$, where $J$ comes from a hyperbolic plane, so $$J=\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}.$$ This leads to the system: $a_{11}a_{12}=a_{21}a_{22}=0, a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}=1$ that can easily be seen to have $2(q-1)$ solutions.

Comment: (cont'd and replaced an earlier version of this commented with this) which seems to match with the Wikipage formula you linked to. I may be wrong about exactly which group that wikipage talks about, but in my youth when I played with (semi)simple algebraic groups the char $p$ orthogonal groups were defined w.r.t. a QF of a maximal Witt index.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the characteristic of the (finite) field $F=\mathbb{F}_p$ is not $2$.

We have a bijection from $\{t \in F \ | t^2 + 1 \ne 0 \}$ to
$\{ (x,y)\in F^2 \ | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \textrm{ and } x \ne -1\}$

$$ t \mapsto \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \right)$$
with inverse
$$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{y}{1+x}$$

(over the reals, this is the parametrization of the unit circle with $t = \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \mapsto (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ )

Therefore, over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, denoting by $n_2(q)$ the number of solutions, we get

$n_2(q) - 1 = q$  if $-1$ is not a square, and $=q-2$, if $-1$ is a square. Therefore

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid yellow]{
n_2(q) = q -(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}
}$$