# how many orthogonal matrices are there in the residue field?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Could you please help me on this? Or just give me a hint how to start.

Task: Calculate $\mid O_3(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\mid$ and $\mid O_4(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\mid$ where $O_n$ represents alle the $n\times n$ matrices where $A^{-1} = A^T$ so that $A \cdot A^T= I_n$ the $n \times n$ where $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Looks like a subcase of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564670/11619). No answers other than a reference to Wilson's book.

Comment: [Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_finite_fields)