# What's the order of special orthogonal group of finite field $SO(2, \mathbb F_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

So I am wondering how to compute $|SO(2, \mathbb F_p)|$ when $p$ is a prime. And by definition $$SO(2, \mathbb F_p)=\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c,d\in\mathbb F_p,\,\,\,A^TA=I\,\,\text{mod}\,\,\,p,\,\,\,\det(A)=1\,\,\text{mod} \,\,p\right\}$$

Comment: I would probably denote this group $SO(2, \Bbb F_p)$ or similarly. This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564670/order-of-orthogonal-groups-over-finite-field , but unfortunately that post has no answers. See Derek Holt's comment under that question for a reference. You can find explicit formulae there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_finite_fields As usual characteristic $2$ is idiosyncratic.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you for the references! And your notation is indeed more common. I upadated in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}$ with $a^2+b^2=1$. Then it depends on $p$, if $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ then $i \in \Bbb{F}_p$, $(a+ib)(a-ib)=1$ and $u=a+ib,v=a-ib,a=(u+v)/2,b=(u-v)/(2i)$ let us reduce to $uv=1$ ie. $p-1$ elements.

If $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ then $\{ \pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}, a,b\in F_p\}$ is the field with $p^2$ elements. $ \pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}^p =  \pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}$ so $ \pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}\in SO_2$ iff $ \pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}^{p+1}=I$. The multiplicative group of $F_{p^2}$ is cyclic with $p^2-1$ elements and $p+1$ of them satisfy $u^{p+1}=1$.

Comment: That's great. Thank you!

Comment: Really nice answer! But let me ask you a question: How it follows that $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}^p=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}$? This is true if we replace $p$ by $p^2$. Would be grateful for help!

Comment: @ZFR The ring $M_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$ has characteristic $p$ and both matrices commute so $(\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}+\pmatrix{0&b\\-b&0})^p=\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}^p+\pmatrix{0&b\\-b&0}^p$ since $p=3\bmod 4$ we have $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}^p=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$. This map corresponds to the Frobenius automorphism of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$. As $p^2=1\bmod 4$ you don't get the minus sign for the $p^2$-th power.

Comment: So if $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $|SO_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)|=p+1$, right?

Comment: Sorry but  am I understanding everything correctly that in this case its order is $p+1$?